# Ruby: Dir.glob not returning any files

Tags: ruby, command-line, directory, glob

I am trying to copy files from one folder into another folder, and then record the names of all the files that were copied into a log file. Both folders are in the same directory and I take that path via the command line. In my program currently that happens through

```
argument3 = ARGV[2] + "\\"
```

which successfully becomes 'c:\user\alexander\desktop\'.
Then I copy the files on my desktop into a folder already on the desktop with

```
system "copy #{argument3}*.* #{argument3}TestFolder"
```

This also successfully completes which I verified from the cmd output and from checking the folder itself. Finally I am trying to save the filenames to a log file with the path 'c:\user\alexander\desktop\log.txt'. I tried to do this by using

```
logFile = "c:\\user\\alexander\\desktop\\log.txt"
Dir.glob(argument3 + "*.*").each do |fileName|
    File.open(logFile, 'a') {|file| file << "\n" + fileName}
end
```

This does nothing and leaves my `logFile` empty. I tried to fix this by changing the `File.open` option to 'w' instead of 'a' but that still did nothing. Then I thought I must be implementing it incorrectly so I tried just putting

```
Dir.glob(argument3 + "*.*").each do |fileName|
    puts fileName
end
```

as a sanity check, but this also outputs nothing. Is what I am trying to accomplish possible? If it is, what am I doing wrong, and if its not is there another way to do this?

Edit 1:
Changing the `Dir.glob` argument to

```
Dir.glob("*")
```

is making it write the current directories files to the log. I thought that meant I must have some unseen typo in my argument3 variable but when I did

```
puts argument3 + "*"
```

its outputting c:\user\alexander\desktop*  I tried concatenating the file path before I passed it as an argument to `Dir.glob` as

```
filePath = argument3 + "*"
Dir.glob(argument3 + "*.*").each do |fileName|
    File.open(logFile, 'a') {|file| file << "\n" + fileName}
end
```

And its still not working as I expected. Is there some trick to passing in the exact file path to `Dir.glob`? I can't guarantee that the program will always be in the directory it needs to copy from when its run.

Comment: That should work - in case argument3 is off (I know your copy example worked), what does `puts Dir.glob('*').to_s` output?

Comment: I put `puts Dir.glob('*').to_s` and it returned all the files in my current directory. putting just Dir.glob('*') in my `.each do |fileName|` loop still outputs nothing though, I tried putting `fileName.to_s` as well. Is there something I am missing about how `Dir.glob` works?

Comment: No I don't think so - how about `Dir.glob('*') { |f| puts f }`?

Comment: Tried something like that and itll only show the current directories files. My workaround now is to just use `Dir.chdir` to change to the directory I need and then use `Dir.glob("*")`. I havent been able to find a way to pass a filepath into `Dir.glob` directly

Comment: OK - one idea is to `Dir.chdir` into the desired directory, then output `Dir.pwd` to see how your system is representing the directory as a string.

Comment: Tried that too and its the same representation as I have in argument3. I worked around it by using `Dir.chdir(argument3)` to move into the right directory, and then used `Dir.glob`. It looks to me like `Dir.glob` wont look down filepaths, it will only search for the supplied patterns in your current directory

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Dir.glob` doesn't take backslashes. Substitute them for forward slashes, even on Windows:

```
logFile = "c:\\user\\alexander\\desktop\\log.txt"
Dir.glob(argument3.gsub('\\','/') + "*.*").each do |fileName|
    File.open(logFile, 'a') {|file| file << "\n" + fileName}
end
```

Comment: And that is the one piece of knowledge I was missing. That makes everything work as intended. Thank you for the help

Comment: Glad it works - sorry for the round-about way of getting there - I use Mac/Linux :)

Answer (score 2):

Dir.glob doesnt seem to be able to take in a file path, only accept a pattern of files to look for in the current directory. The workaround I have for it is to use Dir.chdir to move to the dir I need, then use Dir.glob("*.*") which gets the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Try one star:

```
logFile = "c:\\user\\alexander\\desktop\\log.txt"
Dir.glob(argument3 + "*").each do |fileName|
    File.open(logFile, 'a') {|file| file << "\n" + fileName}
end
```

Comment: Using just one star is making Dir.glob get all the file names in the current directory but nothing I am trying is able to make it go to a different directory and get the file names there. Does Dir.glob only allow you to access files in your current directory?