# Append text behind a certain keyword in filename

Tags: ruby

In directory `C:\Users\Scripts`, I have files named:

```
2A_Apple_VC_20180101.txt
2A_Apple_VC_20180201.txt
2A_Apple_VC_20180301.txt
etc.
```

How can I insert the phrase `Vendor` right after `2A_` for all the filenames in that directory that starts with `2A_`, permanently changing the filenames to:

```
2A_Vendor_Apple_VC_20180101.txt
2A_Vendor_Apple_VC_20180201.txt
2A_Vendor_Apple_VC_20180301.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of the file paths in the directory with [Dir.glob](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob):

```
paths = Dir.glob("C:\Users\Scripts/*.txt")
```

Then rename using [String#sub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-sub) and [FileUtils.mv](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-mv) or [File.rename](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/File.html#method-c-rename):

```
paths.each do |path|
  if path =~ /^2A_/
    new_path = path.sub /^2A_/, "2A_Vendor_"
    File.rename path, new_path
  end
end
```

Comment: So I reworked it a bit from Max into what is below:   #!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rubygems'

paths = Dir.glob("/home/rmikio/Workspace/rubytest/*.txt")
paths.each do |path|
  puts "File #{path}"
  if path =~ /2A_/
    puts "Find 2A"
    new_path = path.sub(/2A_/, "2A_Vendor_")
    puts "New file: #{new_path}"
    File.rename path, new_path
  end
end

Answer (score 1):

You can try [File#rename](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html#method-c-rename)

```
Dir["2A_*.txt"].each do |f|
  File.rename(f, f.sub('2A_', '2A_Vendor_'))
end
```

Or with path

```
path = 'your_path_here'
Dir.glob("#{path}/2A_*.txt").each do |f|
  File.rename(f, f.sub('2A_', '2A_Vendor_'))
end
```

For Windows you probably need to do with backslashes this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20668433/4453714)

Answer (score 1):

Reworked version using Max's response:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rubygems'

paths = Dir.glob("C:\Users\Scripts/*.txt")
paths.each do |path|
  puts "File #{path}"
  if path =~ /2A_/
    puts "Find 2A"
    new_path = path.sub(/2A_/, "2A_Vendor_")
    puts "New file: #{new_path}"
    File.rename path, new_path
  end
end
```

Comment: There is no need to do `if path =~ /2A_/` for each iteration as `Dir.glob("#{path}/2A_*.txt")` do it for you, so you ll have no need to iterate all the files

Comment: but probably its enough for you case)